# regex: Match null or space from start as optional

Tags: python, regex

I want to match null or space as optional from the start of the line. The line is as follow:

```
 Date       Description  Amount
 
 null 12/05/2016 Asian Paints 2,150.65

   13/05/2016 Nerolac GEB 5.86 22,512.65 Cr

 14/05/2016 Hydra 12,412
```

The regex that I used is :

```py
regex_null = re.compile(r"^(?:null)?\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d[\d,]*\.\d{2}\s+(?:Cr)?)$", re.M)
```

And what I got is:

```
 null 12/05/2016 Asian Paints 2,150.65

     13/05/2016 Nerolac GEB 5.86 22,512.65 Cr
```

So the null is not optional.  It is currently considered compulsory.  Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What is the output or goal you want here?

Comment: I want to get all three lines that can contain space or null or nothing. I want to keep space or null as optional

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with optional groups:

```py
^\s*(?:null)?\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d[\d,]*(?:\.\d{2})?(\s+Cr)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UUM5sw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^\s*(?:null)?\s*`: Match optional `null` with 0 or more whitespaces on both sides
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`: Match date string in capture group #1
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)`: Math 0 or more characters in capture group #2
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d,]*`: Match a digit followed by 0 or more digit/comma characters
- `(?:\.\d{2})?`: Match optional dot and digits
- `(\s+Cr)?)`: Match optional 1+ whitespaces followed by `Cr`
- `$`: End

Comment: @Shivam: Did this work out?

Answer (score 0):

You may apply a regex pattern in multiline mode which makes the first, sixth, and seventh values optional in the line.

```py
inp = """ null 12/05/2016 Asian Paints 2,150.65

   13/05/2016 Nerolac GEB 5.86 22,512.65 Cr

 14/05/2016 Hydra 12,412"""

lines = re.findall(r'^\s*(null)?\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (\w+(?: \w+)*) (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)?(?: (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?))?(?: (\w+))?', inp, flags=re.M)
print(lines)
```

This prints:

```
[('null', '12/05/2016', 'Asian Paints', '2,150.65', '', ''),
 ('', '13/05/2016', 'Nerolac GEB', '5.86', '22,512.65', 'Cr'),
 ('', '14/05/2016', 'Hydra', '12,412', '', '')]
```